# How to detect a remote side socket close?

Tags: java, networking, sockets, tcp

How do you detect if `Socket#close()` has been called on a socket on the remote side?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The `isConnected` method won't help, it will return `true` even if the remote side has closed the socket. Try this:

```
public class MyServer {
    public static final int PORT = 12345;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        ServerSocket ss = ServerSocketFactory.getDefault().createServerSocket(PORT);
        Socket s = ss.accept();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        ss.close();
        s.close();
    }
}

public class MyClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Socket s = SocketFactory.getDefault().createSocket("localhost", MyServer.PORT);
        System.out.println(" connected: " + s.isConnected());
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        System.out.println(" connected: " + s.isConnected());
    }
}
```

Start the server, start the client. You'll see that it prints "connected: true" twice, even though the socket is closed the second time.

The only way to really find out is by reading (you'll get -1 as return value) or writing (an `IOException` (broken pipe) will be thrown) on the associated Input/OutputStreams.

Comment: In your example the server doesn't close the TCP connection gracefully (RST is sent and that's it). If you call close() on the client socket, the connection is closed gracefully. You could see this by the different outcome of the read operation: SocketException thrown vs. read returning -1.

Comment: BTW, thanks for reminding me of this "mystery" in the way Java sockets work. I've asked a follow-up question as a result: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155243/why-is-it-impossible-without-attempting-io-to-detect-that-tcp-socket-was-gracef

Comment: The only way to find out is to write. Reading from an abruptly closed socket might not always return -1. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6404085/372643

Comment: @Bruno Please elaborate why a closed socket might not always return -1.

Comment: @Pacerier, see the link I posted. Essentially, there's no difference between a connection that doesn't send anything and one that's just dead (if you're not using TCP keep-alive). You can only detect a closed connection by writing to it.

Comment: @Bruno See my comments over there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6404008/how-to-detect-a-tcp-socket-disconnection-with-c-berkeley-socket/6404085#comment-15210567

Comment: Why does this have so many upvotes :/ It really does not even answer the questions, it is just explaining _what will not work_...

Answer (score 30):

Since the answers deviate I decided to test this and post the result - including the test example.

The server here just writes data to a client and does not expect any input.

The server:

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444);
Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
while (true) {
  out.println("output");
  if (out.checkError()) System.out.println("ERROR writing data to socket !!!");
  System.out.println(clientSocket.isConnected());
  System.out.println(clientSocket.getInputStream().read());
        // thread sleep ...
  // break condition , close sockets and the like ...
}
```

- clientSocket.isConnected() returns always true once the client connects (and even after the disconnect) weird !!
- getInputStream().read()

  - makes the thread wait for input as long as the client is connected and therefore makes your program not do anything - except if you get some input
  - returns -1 if the client disconnected
- **out.checkError() is true as soon as the client is disconnected so I recommend this**

Comment: checkError() is true as soon as an error has been detected when writing, and no sooner. It certainly does not become true as soon as the client disconnects. -1

Answer (score 13):

You can also check for socket output stream error while writing to client socket.

```
out.println(output);
if(out.checkError())
{
    throw new Exception("Error transmitting data.");
}
```

Comment: You *can*, but you won't necessarily get it immediately.

Answer (score -12):

The method Socket.Available will immediately throw a SocketException if the remote system has disconnected/closed the connection.

Comment: No it will not. False. Wrong. Misinformation.