# Why doesn't this server I wrote detect that the client has closed the socket to it?

Tags: c, sockets, networking

In the client, I have a

```
close(sockfd)
```

where sockfd is the socket that's connected to the server. 
In the server I've got this:

```
if (sockfd.revents & POLLERR ||
    desc_set[i].revents & POLLHUP || desc_set[i].revents & POLLNVAL) { 
  close(sockfd.fd); 
  printf("Goodbye (connection closed)\n");
}
```

Where sockfd is a struct pollfd, and sockfd.fd is the file descriptor of the client's socket.

When the client closes the socket like I put up there, the server doesn't seem to detect it with the second code (desc_set[i].revents & POLLHUP, etc.).

Does anyone know what's the problem?

Answer (score 11):

Sounds like you've managed to [half close](http://everything2.com/title/TCP+half-close) the connection from the client side. In this state the connection can still send data in one direction, i.e. it operates in half-duplex mode. This is by design and would allow your server to finish replying to whatever the client sent. Typically this would mean completing a file transfer and calling `close()`, or answering all of the aspects of the query. *In the half-closed state  you can still quite sensibly send data to the side that has already called `close()`*. In your server you will see eof if you try to read though. `close()` just means "I'm done sending, finish up whatever I asked for".

`POLLHUP`, `POLLERR` and `POLLNVAL` only checks the output side of the local connection, which is still valid here. There's a `POLLRDHUP`, which is a GNU extension that should detect the other side closing, but the tests you're doing are only checking if it's still writable, not if it's still readable.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155243/why-is-it-impossible-without-attempting-i-o-to-detect-that-tcp-socket-was-grace), which is talking about java, but still very related.

Comment: Sorry for making such a newbie question, but how do I include that GNU extension into my code?

Comment: #define _GNU_SOURCE before any #includes will do it. Making the server call close() of it's own free will once it's served the request is a much, much nicer way though.

Comment: I've used that GNU extension, but it still doesn't close on the server side.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure on the GNU extension to be honest, I've never actually used. I only spotted it whilst checking the manpages to write this answer. Question 2.1 of: http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/socket/ talks about testing to see if the socket is closed though.

Comment: Ok, I did it, I followed the link you sent and in it I saw the following which I added:            rc = read(sock,buf,sizeof(buf));
  if (rc == 0 )
  {
    close(sock);
     
     
  }

Comment: POLLRDHUP is a *Linux* extension rhat requires a GNU compilation flag.

Answer (score 6):

A remote close or output shutdown is neither an error nor a hangup nor an invalid state. It is a read event such that read() will return zero. Just handle it as part of your normal read processing.

BTW your test condition above should read sockfd.revents & (POLLERR|POLLHUP|POLLNVAL).

Comment: Right - a graceful `close()` is signalled by `read()` returning 0, so it is signalled by `POLLIN`.