# android socket server-side connection close

Tags: java, android, sockets

I write socket client-server connection. Server listens client name and if it's not avaible, server closes connection. With correct names all works.
Client:

```
clientSocket = new Socket("192.168.1.102", 15780);
outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
sendRequest(uName);
currentInt = 0;
updateUI();
```

Then I check, whether it is possible to open connection.

```
private void updateUI()
    {  
        if(currentInt <= 100)
        {
            if(clientSocket.isConnected())  
            {
                outServ.setText("Complete!");
                Intent i = new Intent(this, RoomClass.class);
                startActivity(i);
                mRedrawHandler.removeMessages(0);
            }
        }else{
            currentInt++;  
            mRedrawHandler.sleep(50);  
        }
    }
```

And it always is connected! But server-side closed cliet port. I heard that thus it is impossible to check up, whether connection is closed. How to make it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Socket.isConnected() will return 'false' only if the Server closes properly (calling the .close() method).
If you don't have control over the server socket, then uses PrintWrite.checkError()

See this post for examples:https://stackoverflow.com/a/8268497/1012381