# Reconnecting to an Android Socket in order to wait for Server

Tags: android, sockets

So I have TCP server in Windows that is programmed in C++ and a client in JAVA, Android 4.0.4.

In Android, I connect like this:

```
public boolean sendConnectRequest()
{
    while (isSocketConnected == false)
    {
        try {
            if(comSocket == null)
            comSocket = new Socket("192.168.0.1",1531);
            isSocketConnected = comSocket.isConnected();
            if (isSocketConnected) {
                out = comSocket.getOutputStream();
                in = comSocket.getInputStream(); 
            }
            else
                comSocket.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            Log.e("TCP Error", ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }
return true;
}
```

I typically have no problems with this code on the first connection to the server.

When i disconnect from the server, I call this:

```
public void closeConnection() {
    if (comSocket != null)
    {
        try {
            comSocket.close();
            isSocketConnected = false;
            if (out != null)
                out.close();
            if (in != null)
                out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

So here is the problem... I hit the home button on the smartphone, which places the program in pause.  I start the program again and it calls the resume function in activity, which in turn starts the process toward reconnection.  The connection is attempted and i get no errors.  However, my Windows server records no connection.  In Windows, I know that I am still blocked at:

```
SOCKET connectionSocket = accept(tcpNetworkData->socket, (struct sockaddr*)&from, &fromlen);
```

I believe this is normal.  When I am in debug mode on the Android side, I notice that it returns immediately from the line: comSocket = new Socket("192.168.0.1",1531);  This should indicate to me that a connection is made.

If you follow me so far... I should also say that if I shut the server down, the client resets by closing the connection and opening a new one.  This time the comSocket = new Socket("192.168.0.1",1531) does not block as it should and the execution keeps going.  This is obviously wrong.  I think it is a resource release problem but why?  With Winsock you can solve this problem with this line of code:

```
int so_reuseaddr = TRUE;
setsockopt(networkData->socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (const char*)&so_reuseaddr,sizeof(so_reuseaddr));
```

Can you do something similar with Android or do you have to?  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Just to clarify, are you calling sendConnectRequest() in your overridden onResume() and closeConnection() in onPause()?

Comment: I am spawning a thread so as to not block the main thread.  The spawning of the TCP thread begins at onResume().  In the TCP thread I instantiate a class that is responsible for, opening and closing my TCP connection as well as polling the inputstream and sending message on the outputstream.  In the TCP thread, I enter a while loop after my TCP connection that begins the polling process.  To answer your question more specifically, sendConnectRequest() is called in the class that is on the TCP thread.

Comment: You reconnect only if comSocket == null .. if you hit the home button this may not be the case since your activity may still kept around. Oops sorry didn't see the missing curly brackets

Answer (score 3):

According to the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#Socket%28java.net.InetAddress,%20int%29) the connection is established once you call the constructor.

> ```
>   Socket(InetAddress address, int port)
>       Creates a stream socket and connects it to the specified port number at the specified IP address.
> ```

When you press the home button, your app goes in background but it does not get killed immediately, so your `comSocket` might be not null when you get back to your application. In that case you are not calling the constructor again, thus you are not reconnecting to the server. What you should do is

```
if(comSocket == null){
        comSocket = new Socket("192.168.0.1",1531);
}else{
     comSocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("192.168.0.1",1531));
}
```

(and please please place the curly brackets :-) )

Comment: This works when the server-side connection is broken, but I still can't figure out what is happening when the Android client terminates.

Comment: I wrote in my reply. When you say "The connection is attempted and i get no errors.", the connection is not really attempted because comSocket is not null and you are not reconnecting.

Answer (score 1):

Something to keep in mind is that the isConnected() method isn't very reliable for detecting when the remote side has closed the connection, ([here is an example)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151590/java-how-to-detect-a-remote-side-socket-close/8268497#8268497).

You have to figure this out by reading or writing on the associated Input/Output Streams.

Try using PrintWriter.checkError(), which will return true **as soon as the client can no longer connect to the server**.